# Change svg image color on click in img tag

Tags: jquery, image, svg

Here I'm trying to change the color of the SVG image on click from  tag.
Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uk72ftxa/

```
 <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Svg_example3.svg"  style="cursor:pointer" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to add a filter to your image on click:

```js
img.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  img.style.cssText = "filter:hue-rotate(120deg);cursor:pointer;"
})
```

```html
<img id="img" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Svg_example3.svg"  style="cursor:pointer" >
```

If you need to alternate the color you can do this:

```js
let angle = 120;
img.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  //let angle *= n%2 == 0 ? 120 : -120;
  angle *= -1;
  img.style.cssText = `filter:hue-rotate(${angle}deg);cursor:pointer;`
})
```

```html
<img id="img" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Svg_example3.svg"  style="cursor:pointer" >
```